# yum install openssl-devel dependency error caused by openssl-libs-1.0.2k-21.el7_9.x86_64

Tags: openssl, redhat, yum

im trying to yum install openssl-devel on redhat 7.9, getting the following dependency error, it seems that a newer version of openssl-libs has been installed, and openssl-devel is still depending on the old version:

```
Error: Package: 1:openssl-devel-1.0.2k-19.el7.x86_64 (rhel7.9-server)
           Requires: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2k-19.el7
           Installed: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-21.el7_9.x86_64 (@rhel7.9-fix)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2k-21.el7_9
           Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-19.el7.x86_64 (rhel7.9-server)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2k-19.el7
```

the thing is i can't seems to downgrade or remove  openssl-libs 7.9-fix:

```
sudo yum downgrade openssl-libs
[sudo] password for idm:
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager

This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.

Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openssl-libs.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-19.el7 will be a downgrade
---> Package openssl-libs.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-21.el7_9 will be erased
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:openssl-1.0.2k-21.el7_9.x86_64 (@rhel7.9-fix)
           Requires: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2k-21.el7_9
           Removing: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-21.el7_9.x86_64 (@rhel7.9-fix)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2k-21.el7_9
           Downgraded By: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-19.el7.x86_64 (rhel7.9-server)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2k-19.el7
```

```
sudo yum remove openssl-libs
...
Error: Trying to remove "systemd", which is protected
Error: Trying to remove "yum", which is protected
```

so im not sure at this point what should i do to get openssl-devel installed. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue was resolved by added a new repository with the right package

Comment: what repository?

Comment: we ended up using our internal company repository and it worked